# PHP y SQL - No actualiza los datos el Register

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando que un register actualice los datos en la base datos, los register. Oero no me funciona. la conexión está bien pero me quedé estancado en eso, le doy en registrar y sí registra en la web, redirecciona como usuario registrado pero en la base de datos no hay cambios.

Éste es mi código:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hola Miguel Angel, cuando añadas código, no lo hagas como imagen porque es más difícil de leer y no se puede copiar para hacer pruebas y ayudarte. En vez de imágenes, copia el código en formato texto. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información y recomendaciones para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas.

Comment: Aparte de eso, lee sobre cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP. El código que compartes contiene vulnerabilidades graves de seguridad y no debería usarse en entornos de producción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

que tal?

Podrias comentarme sobre la tabla USUARIO, el campo codusu es autoincremental?

yo generalmente uso NULL en lugar de la doble comilla que estas poniendo, y me funciona, podrias probar con eso, si no otra alternativa es imprimir en pantalla la variable $sql2, copiarla y pegarla en phpmyadmin (o la herramienta que uses para hacer consultas sql).

Comment: Nose como agregar la imagen, pero la tabla es autoincrement:
codusuPrimaria int(11)  AUTO_INCREMENT 

Voy a probar con NULL : O por dios

Si funcion el NULL, disculpa y muchas gracias

no soy muy conocedor del tema, estoy estudiando la carrera de ing en sistemas y cuando me dijeron que veriamos programacion web, me adelante un poco y comence a ver tutoriales.

Gracias por ayudarme, yo pense que tenia un problema con mi base de datos, pero la respuesta fue el NULL

Comment: Perfecto, el problema se generaba por que al ser un autoincremental hay que enviar ese campo como NULL para que se registre el siguiente numero, por ejemplo si el actual es 38, sea el 39. Te agradezco si marcas como solucionado el tema y pones mi respuesta como correcta.

Comment: @SebastianOcaño tu comentario debe ir como parte de la respuesta.